# Http headers passed from Angular 8 are not appearing in HttpContext in ASP.NET Core API 3.1

Tags: asp.net-web-api, httpclient, angular8, middleware, asp.net-core-3.1

I am passing some header values to my API call in an Angular application:

```
httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "xibm-clientid": "Test"
    })
  };


submitSomething(myData: IMyData): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient
      .post<any>(apiURL, JSON.stringify(myData), this.httpOptions)
      .pipe(catchError(this.errorHandler));
  }
```

The request is getting redirected to my backend API (ASP.NET 3.1 Core API) and I am checking the request header as follows:

```
string apicClientId = context.Request.Headers["xibm-clientid"].ToString();
```

The header "xibm-clientid" is not present in context.Request.Headers list.

**Note:**

I am checking this header in a custom middleware rather than in Controller level:

```
public class CheckHeadersMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    
    public CheckHeadersMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(next));
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        string apicClientId = context.Request.Headers["xibm-clientid"].ToString();
    }
}
```

I can read this header when it hits the controller but I don't want to do that because I want to check the header before the controller is called. So why the header is not appearing in the middleware level?

Is something I am missing here?

Comment: Make sure httpOptions is declared on the scope. Should be this.httpOptions = ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `Request.Headers["xibm-clientid"].ToString();`.Here is a demo:

angular:

```
httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "xibm-clientid": "Test"
    })
  };



    return this.httpClient
      .post<any>("https://localhost:xxx/Api", 1, this.httpOptions);
  }
```

Api Controller:

```
[ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class ApiController : ControllerBase
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var s = Request.Headers["xibm-clientid"].ToString();
            return Ok();
        }
    }
```

result:
[image]

**Update:**

Where do  you use the middleware?Here is a demo with middleware,and I can get the header(I check the method is post and I check the RequestPath):

middleware:

```
public class CheckHeadersMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public CheckHeadersMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(next));
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            if (context.Request.Path == "/Api" && context.Request.Method == "POST")
            {
                string apicClientId = context.Request.Headers["xibm-clientid"].ToString();
            }
            await _next(context);
        }
    }
```

result:
[image]

angular send two request,one of the method is option,another is post,only the post request have the header `xibm-clientid`
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Yiyi for your reply but I forgot to mention one more thing in my post!

I am checking this header in a middleware rather than in Controller level. I have edited my post and you can have a look.

Comment: I have updated my answer,angluar sends two requests,one method is option,another is post,only the post method has the header you want,you can check the method and path in your middleware,and you can get the header you want.

Comment: Thank you Yiyi, probably I was checking it in OPTIONS! In POST it's appearing... Thanks for your time... Great day..